# Wagtail: RichTextField data not showing on index page when using urls.py and views.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, wagtail

I am trying to build a very basic home page with Django/Wagtail.

The page model has a single text field, and the view creates a new session if the user is visiting the page for the first time.

The Home Page loads fine as my root page and I can see the text content I have added via Wagtail admin in the body RichTextField.

The problems start when I try to configure urls.py and views.py to to verify if there is already a session saved for the current user. The session logic works, but the RichText Field content disappears.

I end up with two scenarios:

1. If I run it as presented below, the code in views.py works, but
   the *body* content is not shown.
2. If I comment the urls.py *home_views.home* line, I get the body content but the views.py code
   is bypassed.

I am not looking for the best way of handling sessions. I am trying to learn how everything works and I feel like I am missing some basic concept to make this work.

**Models.py** contains the following:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

**urls.py** contains the following:

```
from home import views as home_views

urlpatterns = [
    path("django-admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("admin/", include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path("documents/", include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    path("search/", search_views.search, name="search"),
    path("", home_views.home, name="home"),
]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    path("pages/", include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

**views.py** contains the following:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def home(request):
    
    if request.session.session_key:
        consent = False
    else:
        request.session.create()
        consent = True
    
    return TemplateResponse(
        request,
        "home/home_page.html",
        {
            "consent": consent,
        },
    )
```

**home_page.html** template contains the following:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}

    {{ page.body|richtext }}

{% endblock %}

{% block cookienotice %}
    {% if consent %}

                <br>Consent is true.<br>

    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it based on the following:

- I should not be mixing wagtail page models with django views.
- [Custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-writing-custom-template-tags) is a good way of implementing a function to be used inside templates.

I created mysite/templatetags/my_templatetag.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_consent_status(request):
    if request.session.session_key:
        consent = False
    else:
        request.session.create()
        consent = True
    return consent
```

Then added registered the tag file in settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates"),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
            
            'libraries': {
                'my_templatetag': 'templatetags.my_templatetag',
            },
            
        },
    },
]
```

And loaded and used the custom tag inside the template:

```
{% load my_templatetag %}

{% get_consent_status request as flag %}

{% if flag %}

Some HTML code

{% endif %}
```